# Laravel Eloquent relations condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relation

I have two models in Laravel : Article and Relatedproduct.

**Article class**

```php
public function related_products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\ArticleProduct::class, 'article_id', 'id');
}
```

**ArticleProduct class**

```php
public function related_product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Product::class, 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

I got Article and want to get `related_products` where status is set as 1.

I was able to get them as following code

```php
foreach ($article->related_products as $i => $product) {
    if ($product->related_product->status == 1) {
        array_push($related_tour, $product->related_product);
    }
}
```

is there better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `->where` clause too with belongTo, eg.

```
public function related_product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product', 'product_id', 'id')
        ->where('status', true);
}
```

Please try this and let me know how it works :)

Comment: Putting `where('status', true)` is misleading here, we don't know if the status is a boolean or not. Going with `where('status', 1)` sounds safer to me.

Comment: It's not necesary write the boolean... you can use where('status'), really

Comment: @P.Ellul 's consideration is situation that status could be `2, 3, 4...` and their advice makes sense.

Comment: Don't apply filters blindly on relationship methods. Only use them on extra functions that utilize the relationship.

Comment: @namoshek is right. Normally is used outside of relationship function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```php
public function relatedTours()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Product::class, 'product_id', 'id')
        ->where('status', 1);
}
```

In your logic:

```php
$article->relatedTours
```